# Ubuntu 20.04, Package system76-power is in conflict with nvidia-prime

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, nvidia-prime

Using Ubuntu 20.04 on a XPS 15 9560, I installed the [`system76-power`](https://support.system76.com/articles/graphics-switch-ubuntu/) package to disable the GPU at will as I don't need it 90% of the time. It worked flawlessly for a few months but now I have a conflict between it and a `nvidia-prime` package (probably coming from the `nvidia-driver-440/focal-updates 450.66-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`).

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 system76-power : Conflicts: nvidia-prime
E: Broken packages
```

How do I fix this conflict?

I should mention I can't upgrade with apt as it's blocking the overall process (I could upgrade individual packages, but I'd prefer fixing the issue first).

I have no memory installing `nvidia-prime` but it might have been auto-installed by the driver utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove nvidia-prime with `sudo apt remove nvidia-prime`. If system76-power depends on it (it looks like it) remove both. If you've removed both: upgrade the system and reinstall system76-power, else upgrade only.

I'd always try not to use any force flags..

Comment: After checking for uninstalling `nvidia-prime`, turns out it wasn't installed as I assumed. Nevertheless I went your way and 1) removed system76-power 2) let `nvidia-prime` install itself with the system upgrade, then 3) reinstalled `system76-power` and apt automatically removed `nvidia-prime`. Weird fluke but everything seems back to normal. Thanks!

I seem to have lost the ability to start a Wayland session but I don't mind as some things weren't working right with it.

Comment: @ChuckMaurice Consider adding your response as an answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515 # most recent driver
sudo apt upgrade
```

After `--fix-broken` I still wasn't able to run apt upgrade until I installed the new `nvidia driver`